# Football Database Scheme

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm currently trying to build a football database in MySQL. It should store the fixtures from different leagues, plus their results, odds and some other information.

Is the scheme I just created correct or are there any mistakes in it? If so, what can I improve? I'm also not really sure about the link between tblMatch and tblTeams.

[image: football db]

Afterwards I want to be able to make a Query where I can select a fixture including the points the home and away team got before the match, plus the average amount of goals of the teams. Like the new fields: 'homeTeamPoints', 'awayTeamPoints' ect.
So my question is: Where should I put these fields? In an extra table or should I put those in the table: 'tblMatch' and store the precalculated values there?

I hope you get what I tried to explain.

Best Regards
-bababow

Answer (score 3):

A few notes:

1. You will want to replace "homeTeam" and "awayTeam" with "homeTeamID" and "awayTeamId" which will be foreign keys to the tblTeams table.  This will enforce that the teams in the match both actually exist.
2. Remove the matchID and competitionID from the teams.  I'm assuming teams can participate in many matches and competitions and therefore this structure will not support that.
3. What do you want to know about competitions? Is this a tournament? You may want to have a "bracket" and/or "tournament winner" column in there to store the results of the overall tournament.

Those are my main thoughts, other than that it looks OK.

Answer (score 1):

In my perspective if the values of both the fields needs update regularly and table tblMatch data size is large then you should take it into separate table. if both the fields are updates whenever whole record is change then it could be in tblMatch table.